# How to subtract metrics with different labels?

Tags: prometheus

I have two different metrics I need to calculate the difference for:

`total` and `current{app}`

The expression that works so far:

`max total offset 30s - max current{app="myapp"}`

This gives my a number that I use for an alert about the speed of some process for `myapp`.

However, I have multiple apps. So I want to get the difference for each app. But when I try to get a maximum by app, prometheus does not calculate the difference anymore because the two metrics have different labels:

**Expression**
`max total offset 30s - max by (app) (current)`

**Output**
`{}` (nothing)

And that is because the result of the individual calculations have different labels:

`total{}` and `current{app="someapp"}`

I was hoping there would be a prometheus function to add a label to `total`, to generate the same metric for all apps (which of course would already be a bit nasty).

How can I get an expression that returns the difference per `app`?

**Expected result**

```
{app="myapp"}    333
{app="someapp"}    9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a metric without label on the left hand side of the subtraction and multiple metrics on the right hand side.

This seems to be a case of [one to many matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches):

```
 max total offset 30s - on() group_right max by (app) (current)
```

The `on()` clause indicates that labels should be disregarded and `group_right` indicates the *many* side is the right hand side.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for pointing me to that documentation.